# How to change style using element document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, css, geolocation, jquery-selectors, styles

I'm trying to create a script on a website that takes the user's location and displays the results. I have a problem with the setting and styles. How can i edit style or how can i edit the code so that it can work with css styles in `<div>`

my code:

```
<pre></pre>

<script>
  const address = document.querySelector("pre");


  function onError() {
    address.innerText = "";
  }
  async function onSuccess(position) {
    const geocode = await fetch(`https://geocode.xyz/${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}?json=1`);
    const geoResponse = await geocode.json();

    address.innerText = `${geoResponse.country}, ${geoResponse.city}, ${geoResponse.postal}, ${geoResponse.staddress}`;
    
    }
  if (!navigator.geolocation) {
    onError();
  } else {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
  }
  
</script>
```

Comment: You can review the [javascript style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style)

Answer (score 2):

I've created a snippet with your code. In this case, we are targeting a `pre` element.

```js
const address = document.querySelector("pre");

address.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

address.style.color = "white";

address.style.fontWeight = "900";
```

```css
pre {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<pre>This is a pre element</pre>
```

However, if you wanted to target a **class**, you would do this:

```
<div class="pre"></div>

const address = document.querySelector(".pre");
```

For **id** you would do this:

```
<div id="pre"></div>

const address = document.querySelector("#pre");
```

When you use **id** or **class** you can still target your styles the same way:

```
address.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

address.style.color = "white";

address.style.fontWeight = "900";
```

More info [**here.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById(id).style.property = new style`

in your case:

```
const address = document.querySelector("pre");

address.style.color= "red"
```